# Mixing PInvoke with IAsyncOperation causes Crash/Exception/BufferOverflow

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, pinvoke

I am still working on a UWP VpnPlugin. Without using. It does successfully connect to my test vpn server on a hyper-v Debian machine. In the second step I need to use third Party C/C++ dll/lib. As soon as I use a simple C++ WinRT Component with the C# BackgroundTask WinRT component the app crashes when calling a (the first) C# async method. The Problems start appearing as soon as PInvoke is used.
So, PInvoke is not getting along well with async C# stuff in a WinRT component.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

I was thinking About using managed classes in the c++ component, but not convinced that it might solve the Problem.
Find the complete Project source Code here:
https://github.com/marcusrunge/ToyVpn/tree/extern

Error Messages:

```
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForAlertByThreadId@8()
ntdll.dll!@RtlpWaitOnAddressWithTimeout@16()
ntdll.dll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection()
ntdll.dll!_RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended@4()
ntdll.dll!_RtlEnterCriticalSection@4()
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20()
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()
Windows.Networking.dll!
Windows::Internal::AsyncBaseFTM<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncActionCompletedHandler,1,Microsoft::WRL::AsyncCausalityOptions<&DatagramSocketConnectAsyncOperationName,&GUID_CAUSALITY_WINDOWS_PLATFORM_ID,2> >::FireCompletion() Zeile 162 C++
Windows.Networking.dll!
SocketOperationBase<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncActionCompletedHandler,Microsoft::WRL::AsyncCausalityOptions<&DatagramSocketConnectAsyncOperationName,&GUID_CAUSALITY_WINDOWS_PLATFORM_ID,2> >::FireCompletionAndReleaseOperation() Zeile 46 C++
Windows.Networking.dll!    
SocketOperationBase<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncActionCompletedHandler,Microsoft::WRL::AsyncCausalityOptions<&DatagramSocketConnectAsyncOperationName,&GUID_CAUSALITY_WINDOWS_PLATFORM_ID,2> >::CompleteAsyncOperation(HRESULT hr) Zeile 35  C++
Windows.Networking.dll
SocketNameResolver::GetAddrInfoCompleteHandler<DatagramSocketConnectOperationServer>(void * context, HRESULT hr, addrinfoexW * addrInfoList) Zeile 165  C++
Windows.Networking.dll!SocketNameResolver::CompleteGetAddrInfoEx(HRESULT hrStatus) Zeile 489    C++
Windows.Networking.dll!
SocketNameResolver::GetAddrInfoExWaitCallback(_TP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE * instance, void * context, _TP_WAIT * wait, long waitResult) Zeile 292 C++
ntdll.dll!TppExecuteWaitCallback()
ntdll.dll!TppWaitCompletion()
ntdll.dll!_TppWorkerThread@4()
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

Comment: pinvoke usage should be fine in an async completion handler. The one thing that it could perturb is object lifetime. Pinning and unpinning memory could potentially change GC timing / characteristics, resulting in unsafe but usually effective code becoming a deterministic failure. The specific failure instruction might be helpful if you're comfortable poking around assembly. It would be interesting to know whether the exception was triggered on an invalid call target or on bad data, for example.

Comment: For some reason it only freaks out if I set the debugger to mixed mode (managed and native).

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: For some reason in a minimal Repro it doesn't fail

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere between the minimal repro and your full repro :)